# consulta inner join no devuelve nada

Tags: mysql, join, sql

Tengo esa consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.codAsistencia
           , a.fecha
           , a.mensaje
           , u.nombre
           , u.id
           , u.telefono
           , c.tiempoRestanteBono
        FROM asistencia a
        JOIN users u
          ON a.usuario = u.id
        JOIN contratan c
          ON c.usuario = u.id
       WHERE a.codAsistencia = 2
```

Pero no devuelve ningún resultado... He intentado con esta otra:

```
    SELECT distinct a.codAsistencia, a.fecha, a.mensaje,
       u.nombre, u.id, u.telefono, ct.tiempoRestanteBono
FROM asistencia a LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON a.usuario = u.id LEFT JOIN
     contratan ct
     ON ct.usuario = u.id
WHERE a.codAsistencia = 2;
```

Pero tanto el teléfono como el tiempoRestanteBono aparecen vacíos. Tengo datos en todas las tablas y obviamente en datos relacionados.

Adjunto una captura de mis relaciones y mis tablas con los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ASISTENCIA:**

```
CREATE TABLE `asistencia` (
  `codAsistencia` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `mensaje` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pendiente',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `asistencia`
--

INSERT INTO `asistencia` (`codAsistencia`, `fecha`, `mensaje`, `usuario`, `estado`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(2, '2020-11-11 11:27:09', 'prueba', 2, 'pendiente', NULL, NULL);
```

**contratan**

```
CREATE TABLE `contratan` (
    `codContrato` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `bono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `tiempoRestanteBono` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `activo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `usuario` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    
    --
    -- Volcado de datos para la tabla `contratan`
    --
    
    INSERT INTO `contratan` (`codContrato`, `bono`, `tiempoRestanteBono`, `activo`, `usuario`) VALUES
    (20, 1, 30, 1, 7);
```

**user**

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nif` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `perfil` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'usuario',
  `telefono` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `nif`, `nombre`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `password`, `direccion`, `perfil`, `telefono`, `remember_token`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(2, '123456', 'David Serrano Alonso', 'daviserraalonso@hotmail.com', NULL, '$2y$10$/BfMjo1J8W.UFtQAGTUX9O0Ae9RilA5JFipu0ZVnLWrwDSIQ65NBS', NULL, 'tecnico', NULL, NULL, '2020-11-08 10:59:29', '2020-11-08 10:59:29'),
(3, '45921676z', 'David Serrano Alonso', 'daviserraalonso@pepemail.com', NULL, '$2y$10$wLEOohpZrxbAcFcKC07x5u5gNeA/zeJZwUWNLoec5FsrUfQ5P.9Nu', NULL, 'usuario', 652138927, NULL, '2020-11-11 07:56:12', '2020-11-11 07:56:12'),
(7, '45921676z', 'David Serrano Alonso', 'daviserraalonso@gmail.com', '2020-11-11 08:21:19', '$2y$10$wT2YvsBlypLD.FjADnP0s.vk2liOq/tFM.vHeCGXO3jyGiBReyzsm', NULL, 'usuario', 652138927, NULL, '2020-11-11 08:20:46', '2020-11-11 08:21:19');
```

Comment: las dos consultas son correctas, la tabla contratan no hace cruce por que no existe ningún registro de ese usuario, por lo tanto te da NULL en  el campo tiempoRestanteBono , y en la tabla de usuarios el Campo teléfono esta como Null.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea es cierto... No se como pude abrir una incidencia con el usuario con perfil técnico, el no debería de poder abrir... En fin, ya no veia el fallo por ningún lado. Gracias